# Button gives IllegalStateException when user click on it

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I start the APK on my phone, everything works so far. Only when the game is over, and I start the game from scratch, comes in the Logcat always an error message and the app ended.

This code is linked via onClick button, so I think there should be somewhere the error somewhere

```
public void playAgain(View view) {

    Button playAgainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playAgainButton);

    TextView winnerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerTextView);

    playAgainButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    winnerTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    android.widget.GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);

    for(int i=0; i<gridLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {

        ImageView counter = (ImageView) gridLayout.getChildAt(i);

        counter.setImageDrawable(null);

    }

    for (int i=0; i<gameState.length; i++) {

        gameState[i] = 2;

    }

    activePlayer = 0;

    gameActive = true;

}
```

Instead of the app starting over, it closes and this error message comes:

```
I/Tag: 6

D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    Process: v.example.a3gewinn, PID: 9070

    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for 
android:onClick

        at 
androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(A
ppCompatViewInflater.java:390)

        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6615)

        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6587)

        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:784)

        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26047)

        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)

        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)

        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6854)

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:4
93)

        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:860)

     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)

        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6615) 

        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6587) 

        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:784) 

        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26047) 

        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 

        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 

        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 

        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6854)
 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 

        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 

        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:860) 

     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)'
 on a null object reference
        at v.example.a3gewinn.activity_game.dropIn(activity_game.java:76)

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 

        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 

        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6615) 

        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6587) 

        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:784) 

        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26047) 

        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 

        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 

        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 

        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6854) 

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 

        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 

        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:860) 

I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9070 SIG: 9

Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport:
 'socket'
```

Comment: The problem is in the `dropIn()` method. You're calling `setText()` on a null `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, [IllegalStateException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) is used to indicate that "a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time

In other words, the Java environment or Java application is not in an appropriate state for the requested operation